# ui-router resolve failing after injecting property into controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting this error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$injector/unpr?p0=propertyUserDataProvider%20%3C-%20propertyUserData
at Error (native)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:6:450
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:36:145
at Object.c [as get] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:34:236)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:36:213
at c (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:34:236)
at d (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:34:453)
at Object.instantiate (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:35:103)
at $get (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:67:253)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:53:362 <div ui-view="performance-ui-view" class="ng-scope">
```

Here is my code:

```
// the controller
app.controller('GlobalDashboardController', ['propertyUserData', function(propertyUserData) {
}])

// ui-router snippet
.state("main", {
    url: "/",
    views: {
        '' : { templateUrl: 'views/main.html' },
        'performance-ui-view@main': {
            templateUrl: 'views/gdreport.html',
            controller : 'GlobalDashboardController',
            resolve: {
                propertyUserData : function() {
                    return 'test';
                }
            }

        }
    }
})
```

Right now, I'm returning the string 'test' so I can debug. I do have a User service which I will use once the error is fixed. However, I'm really confused as to why it's failing. Once I remove resolve and the dependency injection in the controller, my application starts working fine again.

Comment: dumb question, are you using your controller someplace else, and also, can you try putting the resolve at the same level as the views and url and not nested inside a view?

Comment: The problem may be with the dependency injection in the first line, then.  Is `propertyUserData` visible from this controller?

Comment: Brent - Yes, propertyUserData has data when I console.log it.

Comment: Dayan, I've already tried putting it as the same level as the views, still no luck

Comment: Here is more info, performance-ui-view is an ng-view and is inside  ng-controller="HeaderCtrl" then if you look at the route above again, ng-view will have gdreport when I call it. The gdreport.html has this at the top of the line  ng-controller="GlobalDashboardController"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove `ng-controller` directive from your partial view `gdreport.html` since you have specified the controller in the route itself, it will instantiate and bind the controller to the partial view. And you cannot instantiate this controller yourself because of the dynamic dependency provided via `resolve` property can only be injected by the router. And your error reflects exactly what it means, i.e `propertyUserData` provider does not exist.

Comment: That fixed it! :D However my $state.go("main.gd") is now failing. I'm calling the state to load the global dashboard partial view via ng-click when I go to another area on the webpage. Here is the code that is called by ng-click. I think, it's failing now because we removed the ng-controller on the view. How do we fix this? https://gist.github.com/c0debreaker/1a9911f875c240772401

Comment: ngcontroller has nothing to do with state.go. they are different things. What does the error tell you?

Comment: I actually added debugger on the very first line. When I clicked the button, it never was able to reach debugger code. Here is the error in screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/AxqFtq7.png

Comment: That error happens when I click the button. Let me put a debugger on the function, right befor $state.go, brb

Comment: I fixed it! :) I noticed my main.gd state in ui-router doesn't have controller I added lines 5-10 and it's working now :) https://gist.github.com/c0debreaker/c47a8a798d323e25698f

Comment: So now, why doesn't my app continue if I put $http inside resolve?

Comment: It will work. But  if it does not you only should know why? :D How can i tell that looking at no where. Please accept this answer since it resolved your specific issue mentioned in the question and post another questions with details on your issue